# drawing bounding box of sprite

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, cocos2d-x

In cocos2d-x, how can I display the bounding box for all sprites that are children of this layer?

Here's my starting point:

```
void MyLayer::draw()
{
    // super draw   
    CCLayer::draw();

    // Iterate through all nodes of this layer
    for ( CCNode* node = ??? )
    {
        // Make sure the node is a CCSprite
        if ( node == CCSprite ??? )
        {
            CCSprite* sprite = (CCSprite*) node;
            ccDrawRect( sprite->boundingBox() ??? );
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    //put this line at the top of your cpp file
    #define CC_VERIFY_TYPE(__OBJECT__,__CLASS_TYPE__) assert(dynamic_cast<__CLASS_TYPE__>(__OBJECT__))

    //these lines in your code
    CCObject* child;
    CCARRAY_FOREACH(m_pChildren, child)
    {
        CC_VERIFY_TYPE(child,CCSprite*);
        CCSprite* sprite = (CCSprite*) child;
        CCSize s = sprite->boundingBox().size;
        ccDrawRect(sprite->boundingBox().origin, ccpAdd(sprite->boundingBox().origin, (ccp(s.width,s.height))));

    }
```

Comment: Assertion failed, dynamic cast, `CC_VERIFY_TYPE(child,CCSprite*);`

Comment: I've changed `CC_VERIFY_TYPE(child,CCSprite*);` to `if ( dynamic_cast<CCSprite*>( child )  != 0)`. But it only draws the box for some sprites, not all of them? Actually, I think it leaves out all the ones that are attached to a batchnode?

Comment: @Ben the CC_VERYFY_TYPE test if the child is a CCSprite*, if there is a batchNode is one of your current Layer's child, it will fail. if you also want to draw boxes in the batchnode, you need to create another loop but replace the `m_pChildren` to `batch->getChildren()`

Answer (score -1):

As you create all sprites in this layer by your own, you can, for example, create simple node, that will draw bounding box of its parent. Then just add instance of this node to any node/sprite you want to see.

Another way is to add all sprites/nodes you want to see in additional array and draw bounding box of each object in this array.

Comment: I have an Obj-C version, what I need is code for a C++ version.